# Generic initializer for Record in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, record, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that initialize `Record<X,Y>`in typescript

my issue is that I'm having the error

X only refers to a type but is use as a value here.

In my case X will always be an `enum` but I don't know how to precise it in the signature also

Here is the function I have written :

```js
function initiateRecord<X extends string | number,Y>(enumX: typeof X, defaultValue: Y): Record<X,Y>{
    const toReturn = {} as Record<X,Y>;
    Object.keys(enumX).forEach(key => {
         toReturn[key] = defaultValue;
    });
    return toReturn;
}
```

Complete code to test :

```js
enum EnumA {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
}

function initiateRecord<X extends string | number,Y>(enumX: typeof X, defaultValue: Y): Record<X,Y>{
    const toReturn = {} as Record<X,Y>;
    Object.keys(enumX).forEach(key => {
        toReturn[key] = defaultValue;
    });
    return toReturn;
}

class AA {
    bb: Record<EnumA, boolean> = initiateRecord(EnumA, false);

    constructor(){
    }
}

const test = new AA();

test.bb[EnumA.A] = true;
alert(JSON.stringify(test));
```

Note that when I click on run it seems to work, but that error is bugging me, and i can't add it to my projct like that.

Comment: your url doesnt work

Comment: Url was too long, ive edited to put the whole testing code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few of your types are a little wrong. The type of an enum is more closely typed as `{}` or `{[index: string]: any}`

Your return type will be a little different and will in fact be `Record<string,Y>`

```
enum EnumA {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
}

function initiateRecord<Y>(enumX: {[index: string]: any}, defaultValue: Y): Record<string,Y>{
    const toReturn:Record<string,Y> = {} ;
    Object.keys(enumX).forEach(key => {
        toReturn[key] = defaultValue;
    });
    return toReturn;
}

class AA {
    bb: Record<EnumA, boolean> = initiateRecord(EnumA, false);
    constructor(){
    }
}

const test = new AA();

test.bb[EnumA.A] = true;
alert(JSON.stringify(test));
```

An even terser (1 liner) syntax can be realised with `Object.assign`, i.e

```
function initiateRecord<Y>(enumX: {[index: string]: any}, defaultValue: Y): Record<string,Y>{
  return Object.assign({},...Object.keys(enumX).map(x=>({[x]:defaultValue})))
}
```

I would however question your approach - what merit your enum values have if they will be immediately overridden?

Comment: Can you explain me how to call it ? Because i cannot do `bb: Record<EnumA, boolean> = initiateRecord(EnumA, false)`

Comment: @CharybdeBE did you see my updated answer? Do you require further help?

Comment: Didn't see the update until you commented sorry, that's what I needed thatnks :)